# Enabling HSTS without forcibly redirecting to HTTPS?

Tags: security, http, https, protocols, hsts

This seems like a silly question but I am wondering:

- How is HSTS deployed without *forcibly redirecting users to HTTPS*?
- How is HTTP content still served from the same domain as one using HSTS? (Either an entire site or mixed content)
- Why would anyone do this?

I'm reading [from the EFF site](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/deploying-https) and it appears that *that* was done:

> We recently enabled HSTS for eff.org. It took less than an hour to set up, and we found a way to do it without forcibly redirecting users to HTTPS, so we can state an unequivocal preference for HTTPS access while still making the site available in HTTP. It worked like a charm and a significant fraction of our users are now automatically accessing our site in HTTPS, perhaps without even knowing it.

As I'm aware, HSTS works by sending an HTTP header:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

So if I access a page on https://example.net/ that sends that header, all future requests to the domain example.net for the next 31536000 seconds will use HTTPS, and if the (response?) is HTTP then the browser will show giant red warnings.

Can someone please clarify this for me? Is my understanding of HSTS accurate or am I missing something?

Comment: I Would be interested to know the answer to this. HSTS headers should be ignored if sent via HTTP so they would *have* to redirect the user to HTTPS to get them. Once the browser recognises the site as a HSTS host all subsequent requests should be sent via HTTPS. To my understanding it doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HSTS headers should only be issued over HTTPS and only enforced by a User Agent if they are received over HTTPS. A User Agent should disregard the HSTS header sent over HTTP as an attacker could have maliciously injected it.

This means the site can continue to serve over HTTP and the user can continue browsing over HTTP at their choice. However, if they manually insert https:// into the address bar, they will receive the HSTS header and the User Agent will then treat it as a HSTS host.

This is a good way of progressively introducing enforced HTTPS traffic without forcing it all there on day one. As users become aware of the secure option the HTTPS traffic will increase and remain thanks to HSTS. Perhaps the EFF is introducing it gradually and may just flick the big 'HTTPS Switch' one day once they are satisfied they can accommodate it.

Comment: Right - but, if you access the site FIRST in https:// and THEN for some weird reason want to visit the same site in http:// it won't work anymore, and you'll get automatically sent to https://, right? (I mean, that seems to be pretty much the entire point of HSTS)

Comment: @HenrikKjusAlstad Correct!